# Simultaneous `.animate()` and `.effect()`

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have an `<input>` element for which I'm doing two things: fading the background to green using `.animate()`, and shaking it using `.effect()`. Here is my code:

```
$myInputElement.animate({backgroundColor: 'green'}, 1000).effect( "shake", {times:3, distance:2}, 40 );
```

The problem is that *first* the background fades, and *then* the element shakes. How can I have two happening simultaneously?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATED** :

Run the 40 millisecond one first : http://jsfiddle.net/96DQ6/4/

Comment: Pleased to have been able to help.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried like this?

```
$myInputElement.animate({backgroundColor: 'green'}, 1000);
$myInputElement.effect( "shake", {times:3, distance:2}, 40 );
```